# How to simplify difficult barred chords in a song

Tags: acoustic-guitar, transposition, capos

I really like a song and when I saw the chords they are : F#, C#, Dm#, B.
And I'm  beginner so is there a easier version  for these chords or like change the chords and use a capo?

Comment: I presume the dver is concerned about the use of 'scale' in the title. If not - then what?

Comment: Does OP perhaps means “transpose” instead of “scale” in the title?

Comment: May we know which song?

Comment: Given the current answer and comments, can you say if _transposing_ is acceptible?

Comment: If you're looking for a tool to do this kind of thing, you can use the app [Chords2Chords](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=javatar.studios.guitar_chords). It lets you enter chords and then finds easier "versions" by changing the position of the capo. Very easy to use 

Answer (score 12):

If you're happy playing open chords as opposed to the barres involved here, take the song up by a semitone - most likely not going to strain any tonsils - and substitute as follows. G for F♯, D for C♯, Em for D♯m and C for B. Pretty simple and straightforward. The only drawback really being you won't be able to strum along with the track - but that wasn't mentioned...

Indebted to trolley813 - by tuning the guitar a semitone down, it will render averything back to the 'original' key.

Comment: If you tune the guitar down a semitone (so playing G actually yields F#, C yields H etc.), you _will_ be able to strum along.

Comment: @trolley813 - excellent idea! I've included it in the answer.

Comment: There are also pitch-shift plugins that allow you to shift the original key of the song in order to be able to strum along. This works pretty well except for vocals.

Comment: This answer just _avoids_ the problem posed in the question. If you just transpose to open position or capo everything you don't learn how to play in all keys. I was going to downvote, but I see the OP really hasn't provide much of description of their actual problem.

Comment: @trolley813 Yep, this is a dodge which singing guitarists have been using since pretty much the invention of the instrument.  It's particularly commonly used by singers as they get older and lose some of their range.  Joni Mitchell for example has not only gone through several different altered tunings for *Big Yellow Taxi* but also sings it significantly lower than her original recording.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis - as I see it, the OP, a beginner, doesn't really want to play those chords, which on standard guitar can only be played with barres. Maybe right now, s/he's not concerned about learning to play in all keys, purely wants to play that song. Hence my answer - avoiding the problem posed in the question. Which you used as a basis for your answer. Although muting odd strings (if strumming) is hardly a beginner technique. Could always use a scrunchie...

Comment: I suppose. But then it's just a non-issue. Question: capo? Answer: yes.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis - except my solution covers it with no capo. Answer: no.

Comment: _if_ transposing is acceptable. I asked the OP to clarify. If you just jam everything in to open position, it skips over a bunch playing technique concerns and just becomes a hardware question - re-tune, capo - or transpose, all of which seem to be about very different concerns.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis - using trolley's idea, it's not really transposition - well. it it, up then down to original key. Does that count as transposition?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the trouble for you is playing all barre chord, you can try playing the chord on 3 strings...

```
F#  xx432x
C#  xx312x
d#m xx434x
B   xx444x
```

You can't strum them in the way of open chords, but a broken chord pattern with pick or fingerpicking will work nicely.

Comment: I like this, however, using only 3 strings will make the guitar sound a little thin if you are playing alone.

Comment: True, but it's hard to really say without the specifics of the song.

Answer (score 3):

If you put a capo on fret 4 you can play three of the four chords using open chord shapes.

F# at the 4th fret can be played with a 'D' shape:

```
%x.x.4.6/1.7/3.6/2[Fmaj]
```

C# at the 4th fret can be played with the 'A' shape:

```
%x.4.6/2.6/3.6/4.4[C#maj]
```

B at the 4th fret can be played with the 'G' shape:

```
%7/3.6/2.4.4.7/3.7/4[Gmaj]
```

The only slightly more awkward one in this situation is the D#m, which could be played as a barre chord:

```
%x.6/1.8/3.8/4.7/2.6/1[D#m]
```

Comment: As a new user I'm not familiar with formatting chords - I'd appreciate it if someone could tidy them up and point me in the direction of a guide!

Comment: That minor is the fly in the ointment - if OP played any barre chord, the question probably wouldn't be posed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on this. Chords where you only play the three highest strings, and you *do* *not* play the bass strings marked with X.

[image: easier chords]

The chords are not in root position, except B, but I don't think that matters, because the notes are so high anyway. It's a bit like ukulele.

Answer (score 1):

You ask about using a capo. By putting one on the second fret, you can use open chords as if it's in key E.

The F♯ now gets an E shape, the B gets an A shape and the C♯ can be played as B7. Yes, there's an extra note, but that's acceptable in a V chord. The slightly odd one's going to be vi - the D♯m, which is pretty close to F♯6. By playing an E6 shape (022120) it will sound o.k.

So, you'll be using 'open' chords, four fingers maximum, all changes straightforward. Give it a try - and you're still sounding in the same original key - F♯.